# How do you modify "Form Data" when a request is intercepted in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, post, request, puppeteer, intercept

I'm on a website and I want to edit the form data before submitting the form. Using 'Inspect Element' on the website, I can see the parsed and unparsed version of all the form data that I am trying to modify. When I call `interceptedRequest.postData()` in Puppeteer, it gives me a long string of all of the unparsed form data. I would like to know if there is a way to correctly parse this string and/or modify the string before submitting the form? `JSON.parse(interceptedRequest.postData())` does not correctly parse the information. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(interceptedRequest.postData()))` does not work either.